# Chachi 420 - Why do so many men fall for her?

Tags: character, analysis, chachi-420

I recently watched a Bollywood movie called 'Chachi 420'.

Laxmi "Chachi" (who is actually Jai) looks elderly and not very beautiful, with a poorly disguised masculine body to match. Still, many men fall head over heels for "her". And this does not even strike as odd to anybody.

[image: Chachi]

"Chachi" is a typical Indian housemaid, probably in her mid 50s. There is nothing remarkable or classy about "her", as far as "her" looks are concerned. How can even the high-class Mr. Durgaprasad start to love "her" so deeply?

Is it just part of the comedy? The film is not very realistic, after all.

Comment: You are right. It's an unrealistic Bollywood comedy flick. Since CHACHI is the prime focus, it's done purely for entertainment and to spice up the CHACHI's character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to say very old movie and I need to recall all things but here is what I found when I see the movie just for this:

As for your first question, there is only two man actually fall for Laxmi, Durgaprasad & Hari Lal. The main reason for this shown in the movie is both is widower since 20 years. Both of them have not needed anyone till they meet Laxmi. Movie covers too, when Durgaprasad first ask to Laxmi and Hari Lal tells same to Jai.

Now for your second question, what is there in her that they fall for her. For Hari Lal, from his first meeting, he accidentally (or later intentionally) dash against her and he feels that's special in last 20 years of widower life. He is also impressed by physical stamina when Laxmi takes stairs to run away from him. That she even follows tradition to bath before she cooks, or she bath while speaking mantras. He sees her as his dead wife has come to life again and he tells this to Jai as well.

For Durgaprasad, the scenario is pretty different. As Jai has taken makeup of his mother in law, he reminds Durgaprasad of his wife is obvious. But, from the first meeting when Laxmi was able to beat Durgaprasad with her wisdom (when Laxmi throws Bharti in water when she was on fire). Laxmi expose the thief servant and prove her loyalty to Durgaprasad. Also there are other good things in Laxmi like the fight she put up when the bad people harassing Janki or how she carries Durgaprasad when he has chest pain, make Durgaprasad fall for her. He also gets same believe as Hari lal that she is the one who can complete him.

The other people, Diraj is dancing with Laxmi, because he get to know the secret of Jai. Banwari Lal (Om Puri) is after Chachi because he felt jealousy for her. Joseph (Johnny Walker) knows Jai's secret from start, and he is there to just make money.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common comedy [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AttractiveBentGender), not just in Bollywood movies. Apparently, whenever a man dresses as a woman, he instantly becomes completely unrecognisable, and extremely attractive.

The above link is to the relevant tv tropes page, but I will also copy this bit so you don't lose hours of your life by going to the website!

> The trope may also apply to scenarios where a male is Disguised in
>   Drag or crossdressing. Sometimes this is played straight, but
>   (particularly when the crossdressing is Played for Laughs) it's often
>   a case of Informed Attractiveness. In such scenarios, despite the "new
>   woman" looking mannish and homely to the audience and most characters,
>   someone will unaccountably be smitten with "her." Hilarity Ensues as
>   the crossdressed hero tries to fend off the advances of an unwanted
>   suitor.